# Server side filtering datatables using orthogonal data

Tags: datatables

I have created a nested data set for a datatable like this:

```
  $alldata[$x]["person"]["display"] = $persona_text;
  $alldata[$x]["person"]["sort"]      = $persona_sort;
  $alldata[$x]["person"]["filter"]  = $persona_filter; 

  $alldata[$x]["tel"]["display"]        = $tel;
  $alldata[$x]["tel"]["sort"]           = $tel;
  $alldata[$x]["tel"]["filter"]     = $tel;
```

I would like to then filter on serverside without specifying a specific field "Person".

This code I use with a regular data set datatable:

```
function filterKeyword( $data, $search, $field = '' ) {

    $filter = '';
    if ( isset( $search['value'] ) ) {
        $filter = $search['value'];
    }
    if ( ! empty( $filter ) ) {

        if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {

            if ( strpos( strtolower( $field ), 'date' ) !== false ) {
                // filter by date range
                $data = filterByDateRange( $data, $filter, $field );
            } else {
                // filter by column
                $data = array_filter( $data, function ( $a ) use ( $field, $filter ) {
                    return (boolean) preg_match( "/$filter/i", $a[ $field ]);
                } );
            }

        } else {                
            $data = array_filter( $data, function ( $a ) use ( $filter ) {
                return (boolean) preg_grep( "/$filter/i", (array) $a );
            } );            
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

How can I apply to the multidimensional array?

Thanks

Comment: anybody? not sure if i explained myself...

Comment: the data is not called nested. Its Orthogonal data